# addclass to specific div in an array

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I have an array of form fields that are dynamically created. I am trying to target the 16th div in that array and add a different class to it using JQuery. Here is the code I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.form_row.clearfix:nth-child("+16+")").addClass("form_row_price");
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't appear to be adding the class to the div. How can I make it so that the class "form_row_price" is added to the 16th div in my form?

Comment: Isn't 16th `<div>` at index 15? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.form_row.clearfix:eq(16)").addClass("form_row_price");
});
```